# Retrieving source address in a recvmmsg UDP socket

Tags: sockets

I am receiving multiple messages through a socket using:

```
result = recvmmsg(socket_, &messages_[0], MAX_NUM_MSG, MSG_WAITFORONE, NULL);
```

And I want get the source address and port, but I am getting an error in the struct assignment when I try:

```
msg = &messages_[0];
***struct sockaddr *src = &msg->msg_hdr.msg_name;***

srcport = ntohs(src->sin_port);
srcaddr = ntohl(src->sin_addr.s_addr);
```

invalid conversion from ‘void**’ to ‘sockaddr*'

Comment: Have you considered trying a cast?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Yes, I did. Digging into the problem I have seen with the debug that msg->msg_hdr.msg_name is coming empty, and that really worries me..... So, when debugging and passing through there, wrong termination happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `recvmmsg` system call is an extension of `recvmsg`. As described in [recvmsg](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recvmsg.2.html): `The msg_name field points to a caller-allocated buffer that is used to return the source address`

That means you should preallocate memory space for `msg_name` by yourself, and also you should specify `msg_namelen`, please try:

```
sockaddr_in addrs[MAX_NUM_MSG];
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_NUM_MSG; ++i) {
    messages_[i].msg_hdr.msg_name = &addrs[i];
    messages_[i].msg_hdr.msg_namelen = sizeof(sockaddr_in);
}
```

So that you can access address when you have at least one message by doing (Remember to use `sockaddr_in` but not `sockaddr`):

```
struct sockaddr_in *src = messages_[0].msg_hdr.msg_name;
```